# Проблема с путем EasyAdmin image

Tags: symfony4, easyadmin

Я использую **встроенную** EasyAdmin загрузку файлов, в данном случае - изображения. При загрузке он автоматически сохраняет не относительный, а полный путь на сервере, и соответственно невозможно использовать этот путь для отображения картинки на сайте.

Как сохранять картинку с относительным путем?

Мой конфиг для поля загрузки картинки:

```
- { property: 'imageFile', type: 'file_upload', type_options: { upload_dir: '/public/data/gallery/images/', upload_filename: '[uuid]-[timestamp].[extension]'}}
```

Документация по загрузки файла здесь, я в ней не нашла ответа:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/edit-new-configuration.html#file-upload

Comment: Из той же документации **download_path**: *(optional) a PHP callable that returns the relative path where assets can be downloaded. For example, if upload_dir is public/contracts/, this option would be contracts/ and the public asset URL would be https://example.com/contracts/filename.extension. Overriding this option is useful in complex scenarios such as when uploading files to a cloud service which creates special URLs to access to assets;*

Comment: Тогда непонятно, откуда это значение потом брать - в базе данных сохраняется только абсолютный путь к файлу (не говоря о том, что при переносе на другой сервер это будет проблема). Неужели нет способа просто сохранять относительный путь к файлу в базу данных?